# Install an SSH key for a server on a custom port in Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: ssh, azure-pipelines

I'm using the `installSshKey` task to install an SSH key that the build agent needs to connect to a private repo in a later step - however when the agent attempts to clone the repo the connection is rejected with the error:

`Host key verification failed.`

This appears to be due to the server using a non-default port (2222):

`git clone ssh://codeserver.dev.example@codeserver.dev.example.com:2222/~/repository.git pantheon`

```
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: $(GitHost)
    sshPublicKey: $(GitKeyPublic)
    sshKeySecureFile: "AzureDevOps-GitKey.ssh"
  displayName: "Use DevOps SSH Key"
```

The `GitHost` variable is in the form:

`codeserver.dev.example.com ssh-rsa ....`

Running a straight `ssh-keyscan` on the agent returns the expected server, but on port 22

```
# codeserver.dev.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
# codeserver.dev.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
# codeserver.dev.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
# codeserver.dev.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
# codeserver.dev.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
codeserver.dev.example.com ssh-rsa ...
codeserver.dev.example.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ...
codeserver.dev.example.com ssh-ed25519 ...
```

I've managed to get this to work by using the following steps (note the call to `ssh-keyscan` forcing a port and adding that to known-hosts):

```
steps:
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: $(GitHost)
    sshPublicKey: $(GitKeyPublic)
    sshKeySecureFile: "AzureDevOps-GitKey.ssh"
  displayName: "Use DevOps SSH Key"
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      ssh-keyscan -p 2222 -t rsa $(GitHostServer) >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      if [ -d "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/pantheon" ]; then rm -Rf $(Pipeline.Workspace)/pantheon; fi
      git clone $(pantheonGit) --depth 1 $(Pipeline.Workspace)/pantheon
    workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)
  displayName: "Clone Pantheon Repo"
```

The `GitHostServer` variable is in the form:

`codeserver.dev.example.com`

I've tried adding a port to the `GitHost` variable (`codeserver.dev.example.com:2222`) but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Is there a better way to format the `KnownHostsEntry` in the `InstallSSHKey` step to get this work first time, without having to manually add it later?